# Replacing text in one file with text from another file

Tags: python, search, replace

I sequence headers in one file (e.g., 'file1.fasta') that need to change to the corresponding headers from another file (e.g., 'file2.fasta'). Notes: 1) Even though file1.fasta has some sequences reverse complemented from file2.fasta, I want to leave the sequences unmodified. 2) The file1.fasta sequences came from different sources, which means the headers display various formats; I'm targeting just a couple formats for modification.

Here is example of file2.fasta headers:

```
>OFAS009268-RA-EXON07 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:OFAS009268-RA-EXON07,probes-probe:,probes-source:Clavigralla_tomentosicollis_gi_512427643_gb_GAJX01006991.1
CATTGCAGCAACTAACAGAGTTGATATATTAGATCCAGCCCTTCTCCGATCAGGCAGGCTAGACAGAAAAATTGAATTTCCTCATCCAAATGAAGATGCCCGTGCTCGAATTATGCAAAT
>OFAS016134-RA-EXON02 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:OFAS016134-RA-EXON02,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anasa_tristis_comp3229_c0_seq1
AGGGCTTGTGATTCCCTTGAGCACATCGCAAGCCTCTGTTCTAGACAAAACATTCCACATTTGGTCAATAATGCTTTTGGTTTGCAAAGTGCACGTCTCATGCATTTAATTCAAGAGGCT
```

Example of **all the various header formats** in file1.fasta (those targeted for modification are the first two headers):

```
>Clavigralla_tomentosicollis_gi_512427643_gb_GAJX01006991.1_103_rc
CATTGCAGCAACTAACAGAGTTGATATATTAGATCCAGCCCTTCTCCGATCAGGCAGGCTAGACAGAAAAATTGAATTTCCTCATCCAAATGAAGATGCCCGTGCTCGAATTATGCAAAT
>Anasa_tristis_comp3229_c0_seq1_0_rc
AGGGCTTGTGATTCCCTTGAGCACATCGCAAGCCTCTGTTCTAGACAAAACATTCCACATTTGGTCAATAATGCTTTTGGTTTGCAAAGTGCACGTCTCATGCATTTAATTCAAGAGGCT
>ENSOFAS009761_p2 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS009761,probes-probe:2,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig5129
TTAAGAATCTCGAGAAAACCCCTCAGGATGATGAATTACTTGAAATATATGCTCTCTATAAACAAGCAACTGTAGGAGACTGTGACACAAGTAAGCCTGGGATGTTTGATTTCAAAGGGA1
>uce-3225_p7 |design:hemiptera-v1,designer:faircloth,probes-locus:uce-3225,probes-probe:7,probes-source:halhal1,probes-global-chromo:Scaffold629,probes-global-start:410155,probes-global-end:410275,probes-local-start:0,probes-local-end:120
AAATCCATCAAGAAATACCAACAACAACTTAAGGATGTCCAGACCGCACTCGAGGAAGAACAAAGAGCTAGGGATGATGCCCGAGAACAACTTGGTATTGCCGAAAGGCGAGCCAACGCT
>Anasa_tristis_comp8051_c0_seq1_A_0
ATCCTCCTGATTGGGCAGAAATTTTGAACCATTTTCGAGGGTCTGAACTTCAGAATTATTTTACAAAAATTTTGGAGGATGACCTTAAAGCCCTTATCAAGCCTCAGTATGTCGACCAAA
>Anasa_tristis_comp8051_c0_seq1_B_0
TAACGTCCTAGGTTAGGTTTCTGTTTACCAGCTAAAATCTTGAGGGCTGTAGACTTTCCAATGCCATTAGTTCCAACCAGACCTAAAACTTCTCCTGGTCTTGGAATTGGAAGTCTGTGG
```

The last two are similar to those targeted, but have an extra underscore and a letter. These need to remain unmodified. Any headers that start with `>uce` and `>ENSOFAS` should be left alone. The new modified file1.fasta file should then look like:

```
>OFAS009268-RA-EXON07 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:OFAS009268-RA-EXON07,probes-probe:,probes-source:Clavigralla_tomentosicollis_gi_512427643_gb_GAJX01006991.1_OFAS009268-RA-EXON07
CATTGCAGCAACTAACAGAGTTGATATATTAGATCCAGCCCTTCTCCGATCAGGCAGGCTAGACAGAAAAATTGAATTTCCTCATCCAAATGAAGATGCCCGTGCTCGAATTATGCAAAT
>OFAS016134-RA-EXON02 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:OFAS016134-RA-EXON02,probes-probe:,probes-source:Anasa_tristis_comp3229_c0_seq1_OFAS016134-RA-EXON02
AGGGCTTGTGATTCCCTTGAGCACATCGCAAGCCTCTGTTCTAGACAAAACATTCCACATTTGGTCAATAATGCTTTTGGTTTGCAAAGTGCACGTCTCATGCATTTAATTCAAGAGGCT
>ENSOFAS009761_p2 |design:coreoidea-v1,designer:forthman,probes-locus:ENSOFAS009761,probes-probe:2,probes-source:Anoplocnemis_curvipes_contig5129
TTAAGAATCTCGAGAAAACCCCTCAGGATGATGAATTACTTGAAATATATGCTCTCTATAAACAAGCAACTGTAGGAGACTGTGACACAAGTAAGCCTGGGATGTTTGATTTCAAAGGGA1
>uce-3225_p7 |design:hemiptera-v1,designer:faircloth,probes-locus:uce-3225,probes-probe:7,probes-source:halhal1,probes-global-chromo:Scaffold629,probes-global-start:410155,probes-global-end:410275,probes-local-start:0,probes-local-end:120
AAATCCATCAAGAAATACCAACAACAACTTAAGGATGTCCAGACCGCACTCGAGGAAGAACAAAGAGCTAGGGATGATGCCCGAGAACAACTTGGTATTGCCGAAAGGCGAGCCAACGCT
>Anasa_tristis_comp8051_c0_seq1_A_0
ATCCTCCTGATTGGGCAGAAATTTTGAACCATTTTCGAGGGTCTGAACTTCAGAATTATTTTACAAAAATTTTGGAGGATGACCTTAAAGCCCTTATCAAGCCTCAGTATGTCGACCAAA
>Anasa_tristis_comp8051_c0_seq1_B_0
TAACGTCCTAGGTTAGGTTTCTGTTTACCAGCTAAAATCTTGAGGGCTGTAGACTTTCCAATGCCATTAGTTCCAACCAGACCTAAAACTTCTCCTGGTCTTGGAATTGGAAGTCTGTGG
```

I have a python script someone provided that I used for a similar situation (but for differently formatted headers). I'm not familiar with python language, and curious if there is a way this script could be modified for this new purpose.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

original_fn = sys.argv[1]
company_fn = sys.argv[2]

pattern = '(uce | ENSOFAS | _[AB]_[0-9]+$)'

map = {}

with open(original_fn, "r") as original_fh:
    for line in original_fh:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            try:
                 (k, v) = line.strip().split('|')
                 # remove trailing space from key
                 k = k[:-1]
                 map[k] = v
            except ValueError as err:
                 k = line.strip()
                 map[k] = None

with open(company_fn, "r") as company_fh:
    for line in company_fh:
        if line.startswith('>') and not re.search(pattern, line.strip()):
            try:
                (k, v) = line.strip().split('|')
                # remove trailing character from key
                k = k[:-1]
            except ValueError as err:
                k = line.strip()
            if k not in map:
                sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % (k))
            else:
                sys.stdout.write("%s |%s\n" % (k, map[k]))
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("%s" % (line))
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the input file and the output from that input file. Currently, based on what you have provided, although very detailed, its actually hard to see what you are using.

Comment: I don't see how I can attached example files, but the post has the examples of these.

Comment: Are you saying that the > proceeds the header and that the genetic code is included in the same file. I don't think that its very clear and hence why nobody has replied to you with an answer so far. I do think its a nice example of a regular expressions problem.

Comment: what is argv[1] and argv[2] input? are these file1.fasta and file2.fasta? This is part of my confusion.

Comment: The `>` is the start of the header/description that is associated with a given sequence. Yes, the DNA sequences are included in the file, all of which are on the next line following a given header/description. I figured some regex solution is required, which essentially targets the header lines with at least the `>` symbol. argv[1] and argv[2] correspond to file2.fasta and file1.fasta files. To execute the script called reprocess.py, I would type, e.g., `./reprocess.py file2.fasta file1.fasta > reprocessed_file1.fasta`

Comment: Sorry, I can't help, I find it still impossible to figure out what you want to do. You would need to specify which output line is wrong and what it should look like if it were correct.

Comment: If you look at the original post, the second block of code, that is file1.fasta, indicates what is "wrong". The third block of code is what it should look like corrected (it uses file2.fasta, the first block of code to correct it).

Comment: But the header on the first line of file2.fasta is nothing like the first line of the expected results. One starts with:  >OFAS000562-RA-EXON01 and the other with: >OFAS009268-RA-EXON07. You don't look to be doing enough complicated regexp changes to make such massive changes. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If its just a matter of taking line 1 and 2 of file2.fasta and replacing line 1 and 2 of file1.fasta with these values, then the code you have presented is overkill.

Comment: The python script is from a different use, we were targeting other formats of headers for changes. Headers shown in file2.fasta were just examples showing the overall format for file2.fasta. I have thousands of sequences, I can't past them all here. Essentially, there are three parts of each file2.fasta headers that are different. The `OFAS######-RA-EXON##` strings that show up twice and the probe-source ID are what differs between each sequence. The probe-source ID will correspond with the header of file1.fasta.

Comment: I modified file2.fasta code to reflect what is going on with the rest.

Comment: Is there always only two lines as header or can there be a lot more information in file2.fasta?

Comment: The headers are always on a single line, the one that starts with `>`. The line immediately below each `>` header is the sequence that correspond to that header, which should remain unchanged when file1.fasta has the headers changed.

Comment: Okay, hopefully I'll have something for you in a few minutes. Interesting issue to optimise actually.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand now what you need it is just the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

original_fn = sys.argv[1]
company_fn = sys.argv[2]

fpOriginal  =  open(original_fn, "r")

for lineCompany in open(company_fn, "r").readlines():
  if lineCompany.startswith('*'):
    sys.stdout.write( fpOriginal.readline() )
    fpOriginal.readline()
  else:
    sys.stdout.write( lineCompany )

fpOriginal.close()
```

Comment: This is close. It's just pulling the headers from the sys.argv[1] file in order and then replacing `*>` lines with these in that order. The order doesn't match between files. Furthermore, as background, the sys.argv[2] sequences were "chopped" up into smaller sequences in sys.argv[1] file for probe design. So each sys.argv[2] header is expected to replace at least two corresponding sys.argv[1] headers. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Okay, so the order doesn't match but the genetic code is the same in both files? If so, I'd suggest you'd read two lines at a time. Make the second line the key of a dictionary and the first line the value. Then when you get a match on replacement, you just read the file1.fasta as value, key, value, key and so forth and replace any value that starts with * with the value from the dictionary of file2.fasta. Its clean and its simple to follow.

Comment: file1.fasta has some sequences reverse complemented from file2.fasta, so they are not all identical. However, I should have a script already that can take file2.fasta, which have the original sequences, and make the reverse complement for all of them in a file3.fasta output. I can then `cat` file2.fasta and file3.fasta, so it has both sequence strand versions for each header, which can then be used to match up with file1.fasta. However, I still don't know how to modify your script to do this. I'm not experienced with python or other coding languages unfortunately.